# why main method prints the values using the code value instead of what i gave for constructor value

Tags: java, oop, object, constructor

i am very new to Java and im learning how to use constructors. I have a Dog class as follow :

```
public class Dog{

private String name;
private String color;
private int age;

public Dog() {
    System.out.println("this is a Default constructor : ");
    name = "unknown";
    color = "unknown";
    age = 12;
}

public Dog(String newName, String newColor, int newAge){
    System.out.println("this is a new constructor accepting parameters: ");
    name = newName;
    color = newColor;
    age = newAge;
}

public String getName(){
    return name;
}

public String getColor(){
    return color;
}

public int getAge(){
    return age;
}
}
```

so, so far i have a class called "Dog" with the above code in it .
then I have a Main class where I put my main method in there which is as follow :

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String args[]){
    Dog dog1 = new Dog("Belfi", "White", 12);
    System.out.println("My dog's name is: " + dog1.getName()+" his color is: "+ dog1.getColor()+" and he is "+ dog1.getAge()+ " years old."); 

}
}
```

**my question are :**

1. Do I always need to create an object using one of the existed
   constructor patterns in my class ? for-example here i created a new
   "dog1" obj which take 3 parameters as argument just same as the
   second instructor in the code (which has 3 arguments too) ?  if yes,
   how if there is no constructor that user wrote it , then how should
   we create obj ? just Dog dog1 = new Dog(); ?? obj creation always
   follow the constructor's pattern for argument that it take?
2. the second thing which sounds very confusing to me is that, after
   i wrote the code in both Dog class and Main class (exact same as
   above codes) , i compiled them and then i tried to right click on
   the class Dog and selected the newDog(String newName, String
   newColor, int newAge) and then it asked me to enter newName( I put
   "Belfi"), newColor(I put "Black") and newAge (I put 10) , and then
   clicked on OK :

[creating new Dog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQSXW.png)

after doing this I have an obj created that is as  following : 
[object created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jy5Y.png)

also this sentence "this is a new constructor accepting parameters: " got printed.
what i don't understand now is the fact that when i run the Main method , it completely ignores the parameters I gave to the constructor ("Belfi", "Black", 10) at the time that i created the new object and it prints the sentence using the values that i gave to the obj when creating the new obj in the main method .

what it prints : "My dog's name is: Belfi his color is: White and he is 12 years old."

can anybody explain me why the new obj has not been created using the values I gave to the constructor ? and it used the values that i out in the code?

Comment: If you really want to learn java OOP in interactive way and permanently feed in ur brain you can refer `interactive object oriented programming book` by vaskaran sarcar from Apress. You will love it !200pages only.i'm reading that book currently ;)

Answer (score 0):

OOP is actually really beautiful, you just might need to expose yourself to the idea where constructors call each other. So when you INSTANTIATE AN OBJECT OF YOUR CREATED CLASS, the clever Java Compiler looks for a Default No Argument Constructor. In this case, you have already supplied one. If you didn't supply a Default Constructor, Java Compiler would have automatically assumed that you had one, if you didn't specify any other Constructor. Understand this

```
public Dog( String newName )
{
    this(newName , "Ain't Got One Yet" , -1);
}


public Dog( String newName , String newColor )
{
    this( newName , newColor , -1 );
}

public Dog( String newName , String newColor , int newAge )
{
    this.name = newName;
    this.color = newColor;
    this.age = newAge;
}
```

In the last Constructor, everything gets initialized, so something like new Dog("A Name") , new Dog("A Name" , "A Color") , new Dog("A Name" , "A Color" , 18) , would have all called new Dog( String , String , int ) constructor either way. But what would be the effects of calling new Dog()?? Compile Error. Because you didn't specify the Default Constructor, and gave 3 implementation of your own Constructor, so Java compiler won't provide you a Default No-Argument Constructor. You take the responsibility of declaring your own like this

```
public Dog()
{
    this( "Ain't Got Name" , "Ain't Got Color" , -1 );
}
```

Hopefully that clears out a little mess??